# How to create a number field that accepts numbers with comma or period in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, decimal

I have an application with a decimal field like:

```
/**
 * @var decimal $amount
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="decimal", scale="2")
 */
private $amount;
```

I want that the form to accept numbers with a format like "3,4" or "3.4".

If I enter "3.4" the application save in the database "3.4", if I enter "3,4" the application saves in the database "34" (yes, without comma and without showing validation error!).

(This is a known symfony bug: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2059 )

**So, how can i accept numbers with commas as well as decimal points?**

(I already tried to substitute commas with dot in a DataTrasformer, but DataTransformer takes the number already normalized.)

Comment: Working solution - in twig form templates
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32231285/564015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround using a DataTransformer with appendClientTransformer, here is the snippet: https://gist.github.com/3394880

Comment: Accept your own answer so that people know that the problem was solved

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I decided to make my own number field without the locale formatter. This is the transformer I came up with:
https://gist.github.com/3411067

Note: one thing I had to do is to throw a [TransformationFailedException](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/v2.0.16/Form.php#L530) to get the validation right.

Comment: Are you sure that reverseTransform should return a number? I would return a string and delegate validation to the original data type transformer that I think is executed anyway..

Comment: No it's not executed. I updated the gist with the custom number type. It's not only the comma issue that was bugging me in NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer. I am refactoring a legacy app that was casting to float anyway with a regex to replace comma. It was safer to design a custom type with a custom transformer than to test how the introduction of a locale formatter could have changed the app.

Comment: An updated version for Symfony 3.4:
https://gist.github.com/FabianSchmick/eebcd59d36eedf1829eb504e1c0c4c49