# Using dot instead of comma when displaying a decimal number

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In db the field is type decimal and is saved like this 0.5

In Entity the field

```
/** @ORM\Column(name="precio_x_ticket", type="decimal", scale=2) */
```

In FormType the field is configure like this

```
->add('precio_x_ticket','money', array(
                    //'grouping' => true,
                    'currency' => false,
                    'label' => 'Precio por ticket',
                ))
```

When saving from the form I can save numbers like in this format 0.5 or 0,5 but after saving the number always return this format 0,5 and I wanted to show it like 0.5

My locale is **es**

Any idea how to solve this using just symfony2.5?

Comment: `setlocal()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php and `money_format()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was using `{{ form_start(formulario) }}` I needed to use

`{{ form_widget(formulario.precio_x_ticket, {'value': formulario.precio_x_ticket.vars.value|number_format(2, '.', ' ')}) }}`

to show the value in #.## format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) anywhere You want to display a number in custom view. I would not suggest to change Your `locale` or do other system changes as it would produce unportable and system/configuration dependent code.

Comment: how can I use this into symfony2 in order to set the text field?

Comment: If You're using `twig`, then use `number_format` filter: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html

Comment: The use case is when I save the data in the text field I save the number with "." but after submit the form and staying in the same page with resetting the fields, the value changes to "," and if I check the database the number is saved with "."

Comment: Use `number_format` twig filter in input field value, i.e template snippet: <input type="text" name="some_name" value="{{ value|number_format(2, '.', ' ') }}"/>