# Symfony 4.4 MoneyType and Safari browser

Tags: symfony, browser, safari

I've an issue with MoneyType and Symfony 4.4. Symfony is rendering an input `type="number"` retrieving a value saved in database. This input has `value="50,40"`. The problem is Safari doesn't write the "50,40" value inside the input. I don't know what is happening here because other browsers like Firefox do it fine.

I noticed if I change value attribute manually (in code inspector) with a dot instead of a comma (50.40), Sarafi works fine.

Current locale: ES and EUR currency.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178332/force-decimal-point-instead-of-comma-in-html5-number-input-client-side maybe it helps.

Comment: At the monent, solved by this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231285/13528730

Comment: try with `"html5" => true` option