# Force number field of symfony2 to use point as decimal separator in any locale

Tags: php, symfony

how to force format to number field in Symfony2 ?

My application is translated to different languages. The problem is that in French I have `1234,56` but it's very important to render field with point `1234.56`

I tried that config but it didn't worked:

```
twig:
    number_format:
        decimals: 2
        decimal_point: '.'
        thousands_separator: ''
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please read these posts [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026050/how-to-create-a-number-field-that-accepts-numbers-with-comma-or-period-in-symfon)
 [github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2059)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override `number_widget`

```
{%- block number_widget -%}
    {% if value is not empty %}
        {% set value = value|replace({',': '.'})|number_format(precision|default(scale|default(2)), '.', '') %}
    {% endif %}
    {%- set type = type|default('text') -%}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{%- endblock number_widget -%}
```